# Flutter, trying to add shared_preference error

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            7.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
objc[67482]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x1faf938f0) and ?? (0x118b582b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[67482]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x1faf93940) and ?? (0x118b58308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/rafy/Desktop/change_to_evo/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'shared_preferences' not found
@import shared_preferences;

Comment: have you imported shared preferences and also in `pubspec.yaml` file of your project

Answer (score 0):

add '`shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4`' to your pubspec. and run following commands to use it.

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter packages get`

Comment: Why `flutter clean` ?